# SFML setFillColor doesn't work to a class member

Tags: c++, colors, polymorphism, sfml

I think I should write implementation for my Circle class, but I'm not sure and I don't know, how to transfer Color as function parameter in main bcz compiler doesn't work with `sf::Color::Red` or just `Red` as function parameter in main function

```
 #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

const int APPLICATION_WIDTH = 400;
const int APPLICATION_HEIGHT = 300;

class Figure : public sf::Shape{
protected:
    double m_x0 = 0, m_y0 = 0;
    float m_angle = 0;
    double m_scale;

public:
    virtual ~Figure() {}

    void setCoordX(double x0) { m_x0 = x0; }
    void setCoordY(double y0) { m_y0 = y0; }
    void setAngle(float angle) { m_angle = angle; }
    void setScale(double scale) { m_scale = scale; }

    double getCoordX() { return m_x0; }
    double getCoordY() { return m_y0; }
    float getAngle() { return m_angle; }
    double getScale() { return m_scale; }

    virtual void drawFigure(sf::RenderWindow& w) = 0;
    //virtual void moveFigure(sf::RenderWindow& w, const double vx, const double vy) = 0;
    void hideFigure(sf::RenderWindow& w);
    virtual void rotateFigure(sf::RenderWindow& w) = 0;
    //virtual void scaleFigure(const double vx, const double vy) = 0;

};

void Figure::rotateFigure(sf::RenderWindow& w) {
    sf::Shape::rotate(m_angle);
}

void Figure::hideFigure(sf::RenderWindow& w) {
    sf::Shape::setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);
}

class Circle : public Figure {
private:
    CircleShape m_obj;
    
    //double m_x1 , m_y1;
    double m_radius = 1;
    
    Vector2f getPoint(std::size_t index) const override {
        return m_obj.getPoint(index);
    }

    std::size_t getPointCount() const override {
        return m_obj.getPointCount();
    }

public:
    //void setCoordX1(double x1) { m_x1 = x1; }
    void setRad(double r) { m_radius = r; }
    
    double getRad() { return m_obj.getRadius(); }
    double getCenterX() { return m_obj.getRadius(); }
    double getCenterY() { return m_obj.getRadius(); }

    void drawFigure(sf::RenderWindow& w);
    //void moveFigure(sf::RenderWindow& w, const double vx, const double vy);
    //void hideFigure(sf::RenderWindow& w) override;
    void rotateFigure(sf::RenderWindow& w) override;

};

void Circle::drawFigure(sf::RenderWindow& w) {
    m_obj.setRadius(m_radius);
    m_obj.setPosition(m_x0, m_y0);
    w.draw(m_obj);
}

//void Circle::hideFigure(sf::RenderWindow &w) {
//  m_obj.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);
//}

void Circle::rotateFigure(sf::RenderWindow& w) {
    //m_obj.setFillColor(sf::Color::Magenta); // if I'll paint it here, it works
    m_obj.rotate(m_angle);
}

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(APPLICATION_WIDTH, APPLICATION_HEIGHT), "Lab 6 using SFML");


    Circle a, b, c, d;
    
    a.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    b.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    //c.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    //d.setFillColor(sf::Color::Magenta);

    a.setRad(32);
    a.setCoordX(50); a.setCoordY(34);

    b.setRad(16);
    b.setCoordX(10); b.setCoordY(34);
    b.setAngle(45);
    b.rotateFigure(window);
    //b.hideFigure(window);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        
        
        //sf::CircleShape circle;
        //circle.setRadius(50);
        //circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
        
        //circle.setPosition((APPLICATION_WIDTH - (circle.getRadius()*2))/2.0,
        //                 (APPLICATION_HEIGHT - (circle.getRadius()*2))/2.0);
    
        //circle.move(30, 30);
        //window.draw(circle);
    
        a.drawFigure(window);
        
        b.drawFigure(window);

        window.display();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sf::Color is a class that can be passed as a parameter. You can read how sf::Color works in the documentation: https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Color.php

Example:

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class MyCircle
{
    public:
        MyCircle()
        {
            mCircle.setRadius(50.f);
        }
        void setColor(sf::Color color)
        {
            mCircle.setFillColor(color);
        }
        void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window)
        {
            window.draw(mCircle);
        }
    private:
        sf::CircleShape mCircle;
};

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    MyCircle circle;
    circle.setColor(sf::Color::Red);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        circle.draw(window);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```